# Reducers state update not calling render function of parent component . React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 3 components in which 
I have one function declared in parent and sending it to child to get callback and child component is sending that method to it's child.

That function is getting called on change of dropdown selection , and updating state from reducer. but after updating state , render function is not getting called.

1 ] Parent method

```
     onChangeTrackList(id, key) {
    if(id) {
        this.selectKey = key
        console.log(id+'comp'+key)
        this.props.fetchLiveRaceVideo(id, key)
    }
}

And passing this to below child 

<LiveVideoPanel  key = {key}  onChangeTrackList = {this.onChangeTrackList.bind(this)}/>
```

2 ] child component - 
    Child is calling this method in other method and passing that method as a props to other child.

```
     _onChangeTrackList(key, trackId) {
    if(trackId) {
        this.props.onChangeTrackList(trackId, key)
    }
}

<ReactSelect onChange = {this._onChangeTrackList.bind(this, this.props.videoCount)} />
```

Now this is properly functioning and updating state in reducer.
But my parent component's render function is not getting called even after updating state in reducer.

Below is my container code which is dispatching this action

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Wagers from 'pages/wagers'
import { getWagers } from 'actions/wagers'
import {getAccountBalance} from 'actions/authentication'
import { fetchLiveRaceVideo, toggleVideosx} from 'actions/liveTrackVideo'

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        liveRaceVideos: state.liveTrackVideo.liveRaceVideos
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
    fetchLiveRaceVideo: (track, index) =>  {     dispatch(fetchLiveRaceVideo(track, index)) },
    toggleVideosx: () => { dispatch(toggleVideosx())}
}
}

const wagers = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps)
(Wagers)

   export default wagers
```

Reducer  -

```
 import actions from 'actions'

export const liveTrackVideo = (state = [] , action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case actions.GET_LIVE_RACE_VIDEO_FAILURE: {
        return {
            isFetchingLiveRaceVideos: false,
            fetchLiveRaceVideosErrors: action.error,
            liveRaceVideos: [action.liveRaceVideos]
        }
    }
   // Below is response  ( I am getting updated state from here)
    case actions.GET_LIVE_RACE_VIDEO_PANEL_SUCCESS:
    {
        state.liveRaceVideos[action.index] = Object.assign(action.liveRaceVideos, {'index': action.index})

        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetchingLiveRaceVideos: false,
            fetchLiveRaceVideosErrors: null,
            liveRaceVideos: state.liveRaceVideos
        })
    }
    case actions.TOGGLE_VIDEO:
        {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetchingLiveRaceVideos: false,
                fetchLiveRaceVideosErrors: null,
                liveRaceVideos: [...state.liveRaceVideos, {'error': 0 , 'link' : ''}]
            })
        }
    default :
        return state
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that are passing the function to update the store to your parent component, but you are not being subscribed to redux store updates.

It would look something like this:

```
connect(
  (state) => ({yourKey: state...}),
  (dispatch) => ({fetchLiveRaceVideo: (id, key) => dispatch(...)})
)(LiveVideoPanel)
```

Also, the state you pass to your reducers is supposed to be immutable. Try to update the liveRaceVideos keys to something like this:

```
const newLiveRaceVideo = Object.assign(action.liveRaceVideos, {'index': action.index})

return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isFetchingLiveRaceVideos: false,
    fetchLiveRaceVideosErrors: null,
    liveRaceVideos: state.liveRaceVideos.slice(0, action.index).concat(newLiveRaceVideo, ...state.liveRaceVideos.slice(action.index + 1))
}
```

Comment: I did that in container. i will update my code . Please check code once.
I am calling same method on load of page in componentdidmount() that is getting called and state update is calling render. but when i call it from child it is just updating state but not calling render of parent component

Comment: What is trackId? It looks like if it is an event coming from the onChange method on React Select, but it doesn't look like an id

Comment: ReactSelect component is returning trackid

Comment: Great. What is the reducer doing? Are you sure it is changing the store when dispatching the action? If the store hasn't changed, it won't rerender the component

Comment: There can be a case that variable liveRaceVideos is getting the same value or same reference in case of array and object from reducer.

Comment: Inside liveRaceVideo i am getting array of objects , so it is changing only few keys's values

Comment: Just updated the comment @Kalashir. Hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the reference of liveRaceVideos variable.

Your case should be like this :

```
var liveRaceVideos = state.liveRaceVideos || [];
liveRaceVideos = [...liveRaceVideos];
liveRaceVideos[action.index] = Object.assign(action.liveRaceVideos, {'index': action.index});
 return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetchingLiveRaceVideos: false,
            fetchLiveRaceVideosErrors: null,
            liveRaceVideos: liveRaceVideos
        })
```